# What is the correct way to use .apply with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a million-row CSV dataset that includes columns "latitude" and "longitude", and I want to create a new column based on that called "state", which is the US state that contains those coordinates.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine

def convert_to_state(coord):
    lat, lon = coord["latitude"], coord["longitude"]
    res = search.by_coordinate(lat, lon, radius=1, returns=1)
    state = res.State
    return state

def get_state(path):
    with open(path + "USA_downloads.csv", 'r+') as f:
        data = pd.read_csv(f)
        data["state"] = data.loc[:, ["latitude", "longitude"]].apply(convert_to_state, axis=1)

get_state(path)
```

I keep getting an error "DtypeWarning: Columns (4,5) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False." Columns 4 and 5 correspond to the latitude and longitude. I don't understand how I would use .apply to complete this task, or if .apply is even the right method for the job. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will be a faster implementation of your program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine

def convert_to_state(lat, lon):
    lat, lon = round(lat, 7), round(lon, 7)
    res = search.by_coordinate(lat, lon, radius=1, returns=1)
    state = res.State
    return state

def get_state(path):
    with open(path + "USA_downloads.csv", 'r+') as f:
        data = pd.read_csv(f)
        data["state"] = np.vectorize(convert_to_state)(data["latitude"].values, data["longitude"].values)

get_state(path)
```

It uses `numpy.vectorize` to speed things up a little (although it is still a loop), and then calls the function with the values obtained from the `'latitude'` and `'longitude'` columns of your DataFrame, converted to `numpy.ndarray` (the `.values` attribute does that).

---

If you want to keep using `.apply()`, you can do:

```
state = data.apply(lambda x: convert_to_state(x['latitude'], x['longitude']), axis=1)
data["state"] = state
```

---

## Edit

To avoid `uszipcode` from raising a `TypeError`, use this:

```
def convert_to_state(lat, lon):
    try:
        res = search.by_coordinate(lat, lon, radius=1, returns=1)
        state = res.State
    except TypeError as TE:
        state = None
    return state
```

If you want to further debug `uszipcode`, and the reason it is causing the error, I recommend you ask another question, with the appropriate tags, and someone will help you. I have no experience with this package, so I may not be of much help.

Comment: You're the best. Thanks so much for your explanation! This is fantastic!

Comment: @user1917407, Thank you! Glad I could help.

Comment: Let me make an addendum to this actually. After some more fiddling, I'm still running into some issues, although I'm not certain it stems from the same issue that I had before. I see that the latitude value in the error log here is much longer than the latitude: however, this anomaly is totally absent in the CSV file itself. Any ideas as to what could be causing this problem? http://pastebin.com/HZeZGNf2

Comment: Actually, what you have is a `dtype warning`, which you can ignore in most cases. Make this change to your `get_state` function: `data = pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False)` then edit your question to include the output from this line: `print(df.dtypes)`. Further protect your `res = search.by_coordinate...` inside a `try .. except` clause, and print the latitude and longitude that raise the exception. I think solving the `dtype` clash will also resolve the `TypeError` raised by `uszipcode`

Comment: I think at this point, it's likely that the issue is with uszipcode, which is disappointing. Even with all of your recommendations and more, I still am getting a type error: http://pastebin.com/gEsQ0c1E

Comment: The problem is with `uszipcode`. You have two options here, use another package, or make the change in the latter part of my answer. The thing is that if you make the change, your program will work just fine, but you will not have information for some of your points, where `uszipcode` raises the error.

Comment: Also, looking at your `data.dtypes` output, the columns of latitude and longitude are of type `objects`. This means that some latitudes and longitudes are not strictly numbers. You will have to drill down your data and figure out which rows do not have numbers. That will also be useful in the long run.